# How old is Wolverine in the 2013 spinoff of the same name?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, age, marvel, the-wolverine

I was wondering how old Logan or James Howlett was in The Wolverine, not at the flashback but at the prime of the movie.

Comment: Around 130 if you take his approximate birth year and then the film is set in modern times. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)#Fictional_character_biography

Answer (score 1):

## About 181 years old

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* (set before *The Wolverine*), we see a young James Howlett in the year 1845 when his mutant gene is activated for the first time.

Let's assume that the fact that he had a fever meant that his healing factor (which is what keeps him young) hadn't kicked in yet, so he's as old as he appears. Actor [Troye Sivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troye_Sivan) was 13 at the time of the film's release, so if the character he plays is the same age, then his birthdate is in 1832.

*The Wolverine* was released in 2013. If we assume that it takes place in the same year, then that would mean that he is about 181 years old.